# R, is.na.dataset colnames error

Tags: r

When I use the following data.frame

```
dataSet <- structure(list(J1 = "foo", J2 = structure(0.1, .Dim = c(1L, 1L
))), .Names = c("J1", "J2"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

then

```
print(colnames(dataSet))
```

returns

```
[1] "J1" "J2"
```

as expected.

However,

```
r <- is.na(dataSet)
print(colnames(r))
```

returns

```
[1] "J1" ""
```

Why is this happing? I create the data.frame in this strange way because I created the code using dput() after condensing a real data.frame to a minimal working example. A function that I am using relies on the assumption that the colnames are kept intact by is.na, which seems to work for most data.frames but not for this one.

Comment: The solution may be convert first `dataSet[] <- lapply(dataSet, as.vector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that your second column is an unnamed matrix.

```
sapply(dataSet, class)
#          J1          J2 
# "character"    "matrix"
```

Now let's have a look at what's happening in `is.na`.  The first few lines of the data frame method for `is.na` are

```
head(is.na.data.frame, 5)
#                                              
# 1 function (x)                                
# 2 {                                           
# 3     y <- if (length(x)) {                   
# 4        do.call("cbind", lapply(x, "is.na"))
# 5     }
```

`is.na.data.frame` is written in R, so we can easily debug the problem ourselves by plugging our data set into the steps.

```
lapply(dataSet, is.na)
# $J1
# [1] FALSE
#
# $J2
#       [,1]
# [1,] FALSE

do.call(cbind, lapply(dataSet, is.na))
#         J1      
# [1,] FALSE FALSE
```

So we know it happens in `cbind.` Now, if we go to `help(cbind)`, we find

> For `cbind` (`rbind`) the column (row) names are taken from the `colnames` (`rownames`) of the arguments if these are matrix-like.

The argument in question here is the matrix in the second column. The names are taken from that matrix, not the data frame list names. And since there aren't any names on the matrix, the resulting second column name is blank.

A quick solution to this particular problem would be to simply concatenate the second column.

```
is.na(lapply(dataSet, c))
#    J1    J2 
# FALSE FALSE
```